# Closing Threads with Python Threading

Tags: python, sockets, networking, server, client

I'm making a Client/Server system in Python that requires the server to be running for prolonged periods of time, for each client that connects it spawns a Thread using threading. When a user joined the Thread for this user is put into a while loop that forever checks for messages from the client. If the client quits then the while loop breaks and the code inside the thread ends. I thought that this was the safe way to 'close a thread' - by simply finishing the code that it had been given to execute.

However upon an unrelated error on my server it gave me an Error - "Error on Thread 40" At the time of the error there were only 4 clients connected however 40 threads are upon?? Is this safe and am I closing my Threads properly and safely in order to avoid the server crashing from memory overload?

```
def acceptConnections():
    while True:
        client, client_address = sock.accept()
        Thread(target=handleClient, args=(client,)).start()

def handleClient(client):

    while True:
        message=client.recv() #Receives messages

        if message == 'exit':
            break

        #I thought the Thread closes here?
```

Comment: Could it be that you really did only have four threads alive, but your error message was erroneous? I'm guessing "Error on Thread 40" is part of a custom exception you wrote, so where are you getting that 40 from? You're not getting it from `threading.get_ident` are you? Basically, can I see that part of the code - the one that raised the "Error on Thread x" exception?

Comment: I didn't write the exception it was just a default exception from pythons 'socket' module and in the default error message Threading also told me which thread the errorr occured on and it said 40. I think you are right that just 4 threads are alive I just want to be safe and not risk having thousands of inactive thousands eating up memory. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Hmm yeah I think you're OK. My guess is that this standard error message simply displays the offending thread's ID by invoking `threading.get_ident`, which, according to the documentation, is a nonzero integer whose "[...]value has no direct meaning; it is intended as a magic cookie to be used e.g. to index a dictionary of thread-specific data. Thread identifiers may be recycled when a thread exits and another thread is created."

Comment: Ah brilliant, I didn't know about ```threading.get_ident``` that's probably where the index is coming from and I'm guessing it works like a stack that isn't popping an index off the stack upon closing the thread.